# Performance testing delete endpoint

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I've been testing GET endpoints using Gatling Simulations for a while now and have now come across a situation where I need to performance test a DELETE endpoint. When I do integration tests, I can pre-populate the database before each test, then call the DELETE endpoint and have the entry deleted. I believe that for Gatling performance tests there is only a `before` and `after` hook for simulations not individual tests.

Any ideas on how I should approach performance testing a DELETE endpoint so that each test has something to delete instead of returning an error that the value does not exist in the database. Or should I just expect the error responses and record timings of those?

Many thanks,
Kris

Comment: If you're planning to test insertions (e.g. `POST`/`PUT` endpoints), I'd think that it's possible to test that and then test deleting what you just inserted.

Comment: @LeviRamsey ah that is a good shout, I am testing PUT as well. I guess the only downside would be that if the PUT fails under load then DELETE would fail also coz nothing got added